# Can not able to Select Cell from tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

Hi friends it is a Strange Issue I'm facing, I am using Multiple `UItableCustomCells` in one Grouped TableView with Section's.

I am  able to Select first Section's rows only, then when I click on another Section's row it's selection method is not working, I can not understand where is mistake, my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code is Below:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //if (cell == nil) {




    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
        if(indexPath.row==0)
        {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell1" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = self.Cell1;
            self.Cell1 = nil;

            txtincidentName = (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];





        }
        else if(indexPath.row==1)
        {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell2" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = self.Cell2;
            self.Cell2 = nil;
             lblDatefirst = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
            btnCalfirst  = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
            lblTimeFirst = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];

        }
        else if(indexPath.row==2)
        {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell2" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = self.Cell2;
            self.Cell2 = nil;

            lblDatefirst = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
            btnCalfirst  = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
            lblTimeFirst = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
            lblInciTime =(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:9];
            lblInciTime.text=@"Date/Time";

        }

    }
    else if(indexPath.section==1)
    {
        if(indexPath.row==0)
        {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell3" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = self.Cell3;
            self.Cell3 = nil;

            btndropDown1 = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
            btndropDown2  = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:6];
            btndropDown3 = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:7];

        }
        else if(indexPath.row==1)
        {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell4" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = self.Cell4;
            self.Cell4 = nil;
             txtViewofdetails = (UITextView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:7];
        }


    }


        return cell;


}
```

**simulator image**

[image]

Please Help and guide Thank you..

Comment: Can You post Some codes from `DidselectRowAtindexPath` ?

Comment: make breakpoint in didSelectRow..are you able to access this/..?

Comment: not blue line appear at selection

Answer (score 0):

Don't load the cells from nibs like this. Instead register the cells with a reuse identifier in the NIB. This will cause the dequeueing pick the correct cell protoype based on the identifier.

Most likely your current approach messes up the touch handling of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

hey try this type of concept and flow of the code

```
   NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell1" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (CustomCell1 *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but i have 4 different custom Cell.... :( can you please edit my code as above..?

Comment: hey @NitinGohel just use the concept and set condition in your if condition and if it nil then create it and also just post code of didselect method dude..

Comment: are bhai did select ma kai code nathi respons j nathi malto select row no bhai

Comment: @NitinGohel bhai thay 6 su main?? means row select nathi thati??

Comment: are bhai sav nani mistack hati but hu biji jagyaye chadi gyo  to sholv nav mistake keta bhia saram ave cell userinterface enable check karelu natu :(

Comment: are su yaar aavu to thay bro pa6i hasvu b aave yaar hase hase but gujarati ma vat karwani maja aave STACKOVERFLOW par :D